# UICollectionView for Grid Layout with Xamarin.iOS (MonoTouch)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I was wondering if there is a UICollectionView implementation around for displaying views (images) in a grid as shown below.

I started to build it with UITableView, but it is getting really complicated if an item doesn't fit in the same row with its predecessor/successor.

[image: Sample Grid]

Answer (score 2):

I came across this the other day, which is similar to what you want to do and may work out:
http://pierceboggan.com/post/56951869926/pinterest-style-uicollectionviews-in-xamarin-ios

It is a modification of a UICollectionView made to work like the waterfall layout that Pinterest uses.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed similar to what I wanted to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: The link is expired. If you have the demo please share it @therealjohn

Answer (score 1):

The default UICollectionViewFlowLayout, in horizontal mode, can do a lot of what you need, but it can't do the yellow cells, spanning multiple rows.

You could subclass the flow layout, and modify the layout attributes for each cell to have the correct position and size.

Comment: Yep, that is what I ended with. Thanks.