# Xamarin IOS Collection View With Custom Cell

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working on Xamarin IOS, I want to display items in Grid style using collection views concept.
i tried with sample collection view example.
[Sample Collection View Example](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/SimpleCollectionView)

But items are displaying as given example. But i want to display items in Grid Style, Please saw the below image.

[image]

Comment: Post some code, or nobody will have any idea what happened

Comment: Please take a look at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/ and in particular https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/#Data_Source for two Cells in one Row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly crude example from a quick test I was doing on that same example code:

[image]

```
    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public ProductCell (CGRect frame) : base (frame)
    {
        BackgroundView = new UIView{ BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray };
        SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView{ BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green };

        ContentView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
        ContentView.Layer.BorderWidth = 2.0f;
        ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;

        cellViewContainer = new UIView ();
        cellViewContainer.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;

        imageView = new UIImageView (UIImage.FromBundle ("placeholder.png"));
        productName = new UILabel {
            Text = "Name",
            TextColor = UIColor.Black,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center
        };
        price = new UILabel {
            Text = "Price",
            TextColor = UIColor.Black,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red,
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center
        };
        var labelHeight = (ContentView.Bounds.Height - 2) / 2;
        var labelWidth = (ContentView.Bounds.Width - 2 ) / 2;
        productName.Frame = new CGRect(5, 5, labelWidth, labelHeight);
        price.Frame = new CGRect(5, labelHeight, labelWidth, labelHeight);
        imageView.Frame = new CGRect (labelWidth, 0, labelWidth, ContentView.Bounds.Height - 2); 

        ContentView.AddSubviews (new UIView[] { imageView, productName, price });
    }
```

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover, I tried with your code. but in my case it shows all records/items in single row. Because the productcell list contains 10 records/items. it displays in one row. If possible can you share your code to my mail id.Thanks.\ Email:   ranjithnagiri@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

In that sample code could you not just do this:

```
// Flow Layout
        flowLayout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout (){
            ItemSize = new CGSize ((float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width/2.0f, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width/2.0f),
            HeaderReferenceSize = new CGSize (100, 100),
            SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets (0,0,0,0),
            ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical,
            MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0, // minimum spacing between cells
            MinimumLineSpacing = 0 // minimum spacing between rows if ScrollDirection is Vertical or between columns if Horizontal
        };
```

To get the cell to size to half the width of the screen. If you want the other element in that mock up you will need to post some code.

[This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) is also a great tutorial on UICollectionViews with custom layouts its in native code but should be easy to translate to c#

Or have a look at this question [UICollectionView for Grid Layout with Xamarin.iOS (MonoTouch)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258236/uicollectionview-for-grid-layout-with-xamarin-ios-monotouch)